# Formatting string into usable data frame

Tags: r

I am trying to convert a string into a data frame, which I can then use to plot a graph with (via `ggplot2`). My data looks something like this:

> Erwerbstätige, die unter Zeitdruck und Arbeitsüberlastung leiden 2013
>                                                      nach Berufsgruppen in %
>                                                      Führungskräfte                                                                         26,2
>                                                      Techniker und gleichrangige nichttechnische Berufe                              19,6
>                                                      Akademische Berufe                                                           18,3
>                                                      Anlagen- und Maschinenbediener/-innen                                  15,4
>                                                      Bürokräfte, kaufmännische Angestellte                             13,4
>                                                      Handwerks- und verwandte Berufe                                  12,9
>                                                      Dienstleistungsberufe, Verkäufer/-innen                       11,5      Insgesamt 15,3
>                                                      Hilfsarbeitskräfte                                    7,3

The goal now is to create a data frame with two columns. One for the text and one for the proceeding number. Importantly, the first row is not part of the data but the description of the dataset.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(stringr)

# Define the string
long.string <- "Erwerbstätige, die unter Zeitdruck und Arbeitsüberlastung leiden 2013 nach Berufsgruppen in % Führungskräfte 26,2 Techniker und gleichrangige nichttechnische Berufe 19,6 Akademische Berufe 18,3 Anlagen- und Maschinenbediener/-innen 15,4 Bürokräfte, kaufmännische Angestellte 13,4 Handwerks- und verwandte Berufe 12,9 Dienstleistungsberufe, Verkäufer/-innen 11,5 Insgesamt 15,3 Hilfsarbeitskräfte 7,3"

# Separate the header from the data 
# (here I assume that "%" is the last symbol for the header )
percent.loc <- regexpr("%",long.string) 
header <- substring(long.string, 1, percent.loc)
data.string <- substring(long.string, percent.loc+1, nchar(long.string))

# Extract all numbers
all.numbers <- str_extract_all (string = data.string, 
                                pattern = "([0-9]+)\\,([0-9])")[[1]]

# replace numbers with semicolon so it would be easier to separate the words later
# here I assume ";" is not used in the string. 
# If it is -  some other character can be used for this purpose
all.words <- str_replace_all(string = data.string, 
                pattern = "([0-9]+)\\,([0-9])", 
                replacement = ";")

# split the string on semicolon
all.words <- str_split( string = all.words, pattern = ";")[[1]]

# trim spaces at the beginning and the end of the string
all.words <- trimws(all.words)

# remove elements without any letters (the last element that originally had only spaces
all.words <- all.words[nchar(all.words) > 0]

# Construct Final Data frame
result <- data.frame( Berufsgruppen = all.words, 
                      Percent = all.numbers, 
                      stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
result
#                                        Berufsgruppen Percent
# 1                                     Führungskräfte    26,2
# 2 Techniker und gleichrangige nichttechnische Berufe    19,6
# 3                                 Akademische Berufe    18,3
# 4              Anlagen- und Maschinenbediener/-innen    15,4
# 5              Bürokräfte, kaufmännische Angestellte    13,4
# 6                    Handwerks- und verwandte Berufe    12,9
# 7            Dienstleistungsberufe, Verkäufer/-innen    11,5
# 8                                          Insgesamt    15,3
# 9                                 Hilfsarbeitskräfte     7,3
```

Comment: thats what I was looking for. Thank you !:)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(text_col = strsplit(regmatches(txt, gregexpr('(%|\\d+,\\d+).*\\d+,\\d+', txt))[[1]], 
                                     split="\\d+,\\d+")[[1]],
                 num_col = regmatches(txt, gregexpr('\\d+,\\d+', txt))[[1]]) %>%
  `colnames<-`(c(gsub("(^.*%).*", "\\1", txt), "Percentage"))
df
```

**Output is:**

```
  Erwerbstätige, die unter Zeitdruck und Arbeitsüberlastung leiden 2013 nach Berufsgruppen in % Percentage
1                                                                             % Führungskräfte        26,2
2                                           Techniker und gleichrangige nichttechnische Berufe        19,6
3                                                                           Akademische Berufe        18,3
4                                                        Anlagen- und Maschinenbediener/-innen        15,4
5                                                        Bürokräfte, kaufmännische Angestellte        13,4
6                                                              Handwerks- und verwandte Berufe        12,9
7                                                      Dienstleistungsberufe, Verkäufer/-innen        11,5
8                                                                                    Insgesamt        15,3
9                                                                           Hilfsarbeitskräfte         7,3
```

**Sample data:**

```
txt <- 'Erwerbstätige, die unter Zeitdruck und Arbeitsüberlastung leiden 2013 nach Berufsgruppen in % Führungskräfte 26,2 Techniker und gleichrangige nichttechnische Berufe 19,6 Akademische Berufe 18,3 Anlagen- und Maschinenbediener/-innen 15,4 Bürokräfte, kaufmännische Angestellte 13,4 Handwerks- und verwandte Berufe 12,9 Dienstleistungsberufe, Verkäufer/-innen 11,5 Insgesamt 15,3 Hilfsarbeitskräfte 7,3'
```